# getResourceAsStream() is always returning null

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, inputstream

I have the following structure in a Java Web Application:

```
TheProject
  -- [Web Pages]
  -- -- [WEB-INF]
  -- -- -- abc.txt
  -- -- index.jsp
  -- [Source Packages]
  -- -- [wservices]
  -- -- -- WS.java
```

In `WS.java`, I am using the following code in a Web Method:

```
InputStream fstream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("abc.txt");
```

But it is always returning a null.  I need to read from that file, and I read that if you put the files in `WEB-INF`, you can access them with `getResourceAsStream`, yet the method is always returning a `null`.

Any ideas of what I may be doing wrong?

Btw, the strange thing is that this was working, but after I performed a `Clean and Build` on the Project, it suddenly stopped working :/

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To my knowledge the file has to be right in the folder where the `'this'` class resides, i.e. not in `WEB-INF/classes` but nested even deeper (unless you write in a default package):

```
net/domain/pkg1/MyClass.java  
net/domain/pkg1/abc.txt
```

Putting the file in to your java sources should work, compiler copies that file together with class files.

Comment: +1 Cheers mate, it worked.  I moved the file to `wservices` and its working now

Comment: If you are using Eclipse,  you also need to hit 'F5' (refresh) so that your 'abc.txt' appears in package explorer,  otherwise getResource() always returns null.

Comment: I found Unit tests were more forgiving to the file's location in Eclipse/maven, but when packaged and deployed the file worked only when I moved it to match the class' location as this answer recommended.

Answer (score 31):

A call to [`Class#getResourceAsStream(String)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) delegates to the class loader and the resource is searched in the class path. In other words, you current code won't work and you  should put `abc.txt` in `WEB-INF/classes`, or in `WEB-INF/lib` if packaged in a jar file.

**Or** use [`ServletContext.getResourceAsStream(String)`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) which *allows servlet containers to make a resource available to a servlet from any location, without using a class loader*. So use this from a Servlet:

```
this.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/abc.txt") ;
```

---

> But is there a way I can call getServletContext from my Web Service?

If you are using JAX-WS, then you can get a `WebServiceContext` injected:

```
@Resource
private WebServiceContext wsContext;
```

And then get the `ServletContext` from it:

```
ServletContext sContext= wsContext.getMessageContext()
                             .get(MessageContext.SERVLET_CONTEXT));
```

Comment: But is there a way I can call `getServletContext` from my Web Service?

Answer (score 31):

Instead of

```
InputStream fstream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("abc.txt");
```

use

```
InputStream fstream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("abc.txt");
```

In this way it will look from the root, not from the path of the current invoking class

Comment: man, 3 hours I was fighting with null pointer and BOOM, ur comment...thanx)

Answer (score 11):

I think this way you can get the file from "anywhere" (including server locations) and you do not need to care about where to put it.

It's usually a bad practice having to care about such things.

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("abc.properties");
```

Comment: so glad i came across this answer. many thanks! absolutely nothing else worked for me.

Comment: I'm with the commenter before me: nothing else worked! But your solution is godsend. First try, no problems. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if this applies to JAX-WS, but for JAX-RS I was able to access a file by injecting a ServletContext and then calling getResourceAsStream() on it:

```
@Context ServletContext servletContext;
...
InputStream is = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/test_model.js");
```

Note that, at least in GlassFish 3.1, the path had to be absolute, i.e., start with slash. More here: [How do I use a properties file with jax-rs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903472/how-do-i-use-a-properties-file-with-jax-rs/)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I changed from Websphere 8.5 to WebSphere Liberty.

I utilized `FileInputStream` instead of `getResourceAsStream()`, because for some reason WebSphere Liberty can't locate the file in the `WEB-INF` folder.

The script was :

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(getServletContext().getRealPath("/") 
                        + "\WEBINF\properties\myProperties.properties")
```

Note:
I used this script only for development.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I searched for the solution for quite a while:
It appears that the string parameter is case sensitive. So if your filename is abc.TXT but you search for abc.txt, eclipse will find it - the executable JAR file won't.