# Write to a file stream returned from getResourceAsStream()

Tags: java, web-services, file-io

I am getting a a `InputStream` from `getResourceAsStream()`, and I managed to read from the file by passing the returned `InputStream` to a `BufferedReader`.

Is there any way I can write to the file as well?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Not directly, no - `getResourceAsStream()` is intended to return a view on read-only resources.

If you know that the resource is a writeable file, though, you can jump through some hoops, e.g.

```
URL resourceUrl = getClass().getResource(path);
File file = new File(resourceUrl.toURI());
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

This should work nicely on unix-style systems, but windows file paths might give this indigestion. Try it and find out, though, you might be OK.

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not ok.  I had to add a `toString()` to the `toUri()`: `new File(resourceUrl.toURI().toString());`.  

But now, a `FileNoFoundException` is being thrown in the third line: `"vfszip:\C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\deploy\IMAss4.war\WEB-INF\classes\wservices\markers.txt (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)"`

Comment: @Andreas: OK, that's JBoss's internal virtual filesystem getting in the way. This is why what you're trying to do is inadvisable.

Comment: So then, is there any way I can put the file in the `Web Pages` folder and read/write to it from my Web Service?  (Look at my question here for my structure of documents: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797162/getresourceasstream-is-always-returning-null)

Answer (score 11):

> Is there any way I can write to the
>   file as well?

Who says it's a file? The whole point of `getResourceAsStream()` is to abstract that away because it might well not be true. Specifically, the resource may be situated in a JAR file, may be read from a HTTP server, or really anything that the implementer of the `ClassLoader` could imagine.

You really shouldn't *want* to write to a resource that's part of your program distribution. It's conceptually the wrong thing to do in most cases. Settings or User-specific data should go to the [Preferences API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/) or the user's home directory.

Comment: Then is there a way I can access a file that is located where the jsp pages are?  ie directly in the `Web Pages` folder?  from the Web Service ie

Comment: This answer doesn't provide an answer. It should be a comment.