# Accessing a file (for writing) from a JBoss Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, file-io, jboss

Let's say I have this structure of my Java Web Application:

```
TheProject
  -- [Web Pages]
  -- -- abc.txt
  -- -- index.jsp
  -- [Source Packages]
  -- -- [wservices]
  -- -- -- WS.java
```

`WS.java` is my Web Service, which is situated in a `wservices` package.  Now from this service, I need to access the `abc.txt` file and write to it.

These are my urls:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/TheProject/WS  <- the webservice
http://127.0.0.1:8080/TheProject/abc.txt <- the file I want to access
```

To read the file, I [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797162/getresourceasstream-is-always-returning-null) with `getResourceAsStream` and I was successful in reading from it.  But now I also want to write to this file, and I [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797367/write-to-a-file-stream-returned-from-getresourceasstream) such a method but failed.

Is there a way I can get access to the `abc.txt` file from `WS.java` and be able to successfully read from and write to it?

Answer (score 0):

You must locate the file first, and open a File object on it which you can then use as usual.  Start with the URL returned by "getResource" and work your way from there.

Note:  This trick makes assumptions on how the way the application server deploys your WAR-file, and will make it non-portable.

Comment: I tried that (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797367/write-to-a-file-stream-returned-from-getresourceasstream/2797381#2797381) but it failed with a `FileNotFoundException` exception.

Comment: Then you need closer investigation on the URL returned.

Answer (score 0):

well, access for reading is possible. You can get access to it by accessing file from the following path: (I'm assuming that your web service is packed inside of the WAR file)

```
@Resource
private WebServiceContext context;
......
// receive the realpath to foo.txt inside of web-archive deployment
((ServletContext )context.getMessageContext().get(MessageContext.SERVLET_CONTEXT)).getRealPath("foo.txt")
```

But writting there is a bad idea in general - JBOSS will unpack your application to some tmp folder. So every time your application restarts you'll receive the new foo.txt