# Google App Engine Java: Reading in an html file problems

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm trying to read in an html file as a string using InputStream but no matter what I try I keep getting a null pointer exception.  The File I am trying to read is at "/war/index.html" and the code to read it in looks like this:

```
File f = new File(path);
        ServletContext context = getServletContext();
        InputStream is = context.getResourceAsStream(f.getAbsolutePath());
        int data = is.read();
```

As soon as I call is.read() it gives me a NullPointerException.  Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: You may find an answer here.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797162/getresourceasstream-is-always-returning-null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here seems to be 2 issues combined:

- by default when you create file with relative path, working directory in this case is `java.dir`, which in most cases is not the same, as `webapps` folder of web-container
- you seem to have extra `war` indicator in your path.

Please check how ServletContext [resolves files](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourcePaths%28java.lang.String%29).

So you simply need to use:

```
ServletContext context = getServletContext();
InputStream is = context.getResourceAsStream("/index.html");
```