# How to read properties (or any other text) file in Java Spring MVC app?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I need to read java properties file inside my Spring MVC app but I can't find the way to do that. I tried several answers from similar question here on SO, but I was unsuccessful. I'm new to Java, and especially Spring MVC so I probably messed up something.

I'm not sure anymore that the file is being successfully deployed. I'm using Tomcat btw.

Comment: Please show how you attempted to read it.

Comment: It would be good to know your spring mvc version, do you use xml config or java, how your war looks like(if you have one) and other detail.

Comment: `Properties.load(Reader)` comes to mind: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797162/getresourceasstream-is-always-returning-null

Answer (score 11):

If you are using Spring 3.1+ you can use the [@PropertySource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) annotation:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/com/example/app.properties")
public class AppConfig {
    // create beans
}
```

or for XML-based configuration you can use the [<context:property-placeholder>](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer):

```
<beans>
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:com/example/app.properties"/>
    <!-- bean declarations -->
</beans>
```

then you can autowire the key in the properties file using the [@Value](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) annotation:

```
@Value("${property.key}") String propertyValue;
```

Read more details in the [Spring reference docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer).

Comment: I tried doing this way. But am getting the value as null. It is not reading the value of the property.

Comment: Please make sure that the class that contains the `@Value` annotation is annotated with `@Component` (or any of the other component stereotype annotations).

Answer (score 3):

You can have properties files automatically loaded in Spring by using the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`.

Here is an example of configuring a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` using Spring JavaConfig:

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer props = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    props.setLocations(new Resource[] {
            new ClassPathResource("/config/myconfig.properties"),
            new ClassPathResource("version.properties")
    });
}
```

This will load the properties from the files above on the classpath.

You can use these properties in property replacements within your application.  For example, assume that there is a property in one of those files above named `myprop`.  You could inject `myprop`'s value into a field using the following:

```
@Value(${myprop})
private String someProperty;
```

You can also access the values of the properties by injecting Spring's `Environment` object into your classes.

```
@Resource
private Environment environment;

public void doSomething() {
   String myPropValue = environment.getProperty("myprop");
}
```

---

In order to read any old file from within a web application the link that Frederic posted in the comments above provides a good explanation of the normal classloader hurdles one encounters when attempting to read files from within their war file and the solutions around it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code.

Add this to servelt-context.xml

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config.properties"/>
```

And to access the contents of config file in java,

```
@Value("${KEY}")
private String value;
```