# reading a pdf via his Path

Tags: java, maven, netbeans-7, null-pointer

I ve placed a pdf docment in the same place of my java class but I still got a NullPointer
error.
I need to  place the pdf document in the same place of my class. 
this's my code:

```
    private static final String sourcePath = "rockTest.pdf";
    inputStream = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(sourcePath);
```

**sourcePath is the name of the pdf document.**

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [getResourceAsStream() is always returning null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797162/getresourceasstream-is-always-returning-null)

Comment: Where is the pdf file really located `src/test/resources` ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I placed at the same place of the java class: into the src package

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below

```
InputStream in = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("rockTest.pdf");
```