# getResourceAsStream returns NullpointerException

Tags: java, spring-boot, inputstream, request-mapping

In Spring, I want to get the image to display on my browser.  The image is located in my main project i.e.

```
> myproject
   - src
   - target
   - img.png
```

This means that img.png is in the root so I dont supply any path but it returns a `NullPointerException`. I tried adding the image in src and I changed path to `src\img.png` but still gave NPE.

Please note, this project is using Maven.

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1792) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1769) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1744) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(IOUtils.java:462) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
```

Here is the code I use:

```
InputStream in = DataService.class.getResourceAsStream("img.png");

        final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);

        result.setData(new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(IOUtils.toByteArray(in), headers, HttpStatus.CREATED));
```

**Comments on this question being marked for closure:**

- The question is related to programming as the API [getResourceAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) says this:

> Returns
> A URL object or null if no resource with this name is found

My code was returning `null` even when I tried adding `img.png` to different locations.

- This question is not a duplicate of this: [getResourceAsStream() is always returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797162/getresourceasstream-is-always-returning-null)

The answer in that question says that the file must be in the same directory as `this` but in this question, even though I added the image to the same location where class `DataService` was, it did not work.

Comment: Does it *actually* *`return`* a `NullPointerException`, or do you just mean it returns `null`?

Comment: I will update my answer, thats what it says!

Comment: Put it in the same directory as `DataService.java` and use `getResourceAsStream("img.png")`

Comment: @erickson I still get the same error

Comment: Build the project and look into build or target folder to check foe existence of img.png file. If its a maven project then put the image in src/resources folder.

Comment: I have copied the file myself and also built it several times but still does not work

Comment: Where you copied it? Inside target folder?

Comment: @Braj since its a Maven project, adding to resources worked

Comment: That's how maven organize the project structure.

Comment: no its not @Ravindrababu I checked that question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the project setup is done using `Maven`, adding the image to `resources` folder worked. Nothing from the code changed:

```
DataService.class.getClassLoader().getResource("img.png")
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that `/src` is probably the root of classpath (it depends on how you compile the project), and so you should put the img.png to `src` folder and the following code would work

`DataService.class.getResourceAsStream("img.png");`

Generally the getResourceAsStream() looks for the files from the root of classpath.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to do a small change, it's getResourceAsStream("/img.png") not getResourceAsStream("img.png").

I hope this will help.

Comment: Did not work with that change

Comment: Are you sure than, that the NPE is because of image path ?

Because the following works perfectly fine for me:

`BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(DataService.class.getResourceAsStream("/img.jpg"));
  if (img != null) {
   System.out.println(" not null");
  }`