# Get file resource in a Jersey 3

Tags: java, jersey

I am running a web application using Jersey. In my controller, I am trying to get a file in `src/main/resources` folder.

My folder structure is:

[image: folder structure]

My gradle dependencies are:

```
dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers', name: 'jersey-container-servlet', version: '3.0.2'
    implementation group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.inject', name: 'jersey-hk2', version: '3.0.2'
    implementation group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.media', name: 'jersey-media-moxy', version: '3.0.2'
}
```

My code is:

```
@GET
@Path(value = "/log/details/{fileId}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<IngestionLogs> getIngestionLogDetails(@PathParam("fileId") String fileId) {
    List<IngestionLogs> logs = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        InputStream stream; // how do I get this?
        List<IngestionLogs> errors = TsvFileValidators.parseObject(stream);
        logs.addAll(errors);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    return logs;
}
```

How do I get an `InputStream` for this file?

Comment: See if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797162/getresourceasstream-is-always-returning-null

Comment: @user7294900 How do I get the ServletContext in Jersey 3.0.2?

Comment: Try `@Context private ServletContext servletContext;`

Comment: tried it already. Not able to import `jakarta.servlet.ServletContext`
https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/servletcontext

Comment: If you are missing add relevant jar as `jakarta.servlet-api-5.0.0.jar`

Comment: @user7294900 Yes, but shouldn't it be available already from Tomcat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it by [servletContext.getResourceAsStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797162/getresourceasstream-is-always-returning-null)

> ```
>  InputStream is = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/test_model.js");
> ```

Add `ServletContext` using `@Context`

```
@Context private ServletContext servletContext;
```

If you are missing import `jakarta.servlet.ServletContext` add to dependency [jakarta.servlet-api](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet/jakarta.servlet-api/5.0.0)